# exit tmux window without quitting the Terminal program

Tags: terminal, tmux

OK I'm new to this. I installed `tmux` to run a several days experiment. After typing `tmux new -s name` I got a new window with green banner at the bottom. I compile and run java program. Now I do not know how to exit the window (while leave it running). The bash (or whatever) cursor is not responding because the java program is still running.  My solution so far is to quit the Terminal program completely and reopen it again. Any ideas on how to quit the tmux window without exiting the whole Terminal program?

Comment: `man tmux | less -p detach`

Comment: For more interactive way, you can do `Ctrl+b s`which will list sessions, navigate to the one you want to kill and type `:kill-session`.

Comment: I just ended up doing `exit` and it worked on my Mac terminal.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Detach from currently attached session

Session

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>b</kbd> `:detach`

Screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>a</kbd> `:detach`

Comment: You then need to run `tmux attach` to enter the open session again after re-connecting.

Comment: I've always done `ENTER ~ .` This seems nicer.

Comment: Is there space between `~` and `.` and it also returns `permission denied: /home/folder` @ThomasEding

Comment: @alper No spaces at all in the expression I typed above.

Answer (score 18):

The previous answers are incomplete, I believe. What `:detach` does is to shut down the viewports that are displaying tmux activity. However, tmux itself is still running in the background as you can see by running `ps`:

`myuser 1799  0.0  0.0  2500052 4632   ??  Ss   21Feb16   0:48.39 tmux new-session -s Dev`

In fact, even if you quit terminal and start it up again, any tmux processes are STILL running in the background.

To actually kill the tmux process itself, you have to do:

`tmux kill-session [-t session_name]`

or simply:

`kill -9 1799`

Comment: Imho, it would make more sense to comment about some answer's deficiencies under that particular answer and leave your post as a complete and contained answer without requiring readers to find out which answers are previous and then analyse them.

Comment: I think OP specifically wanted the background process (java, in his case) to continue running, so killing it would be counter-productive. More interesting would be to re-attach later to the detached process with `tmux attach-session`.

Comment: Using `kill -9` is absolutely the Wrong Way(tm) to do this. This sends a `SIGKILL` signal which will not allow the process to clean up after itself, which can cause serious problems with dangling resources. `SIGKILL` should only be used when a process has already politely been asked to cleanup and shut down via `SIGTERM` or similar and, for whatever reason, refuses to do so; even then, one should still avoid sending `SIGKILL` if they can. This answer infers (incorrectly) that it should be one of the first things a person should do to shutdown a background process like a tmux server.